# ¿Por qué funciona en xampp y en godaddy no?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

No sé cómo formular bien esta pregunta. Tengo este código

```
<head>
    <title>Universalistas</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/images/logo.png"/>
</head>

</body>

<?php ob_start();

    include("conection.php");

if(isset($_POST["send"]))
{

    function validate_mail($mail)
    {
        if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-_.+%]+@[A-Za-z0-9-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/", $mail)) return true;
        else return false;
    }//Fin funcion validate_mail

    $no_blank = count_chars($_POST["user"], 1);
    if(!empty($no_blank[32])) echo "<script>alert('El campo usuario no debe contener espacios en blanco.');history.back();</script>";
    elseif(empty($_POST["user"])) echo "<script>alert('Ingresa tu usuario.');history.back();</script>";
    elseif(empty($_POST["password"])) echo "<script>alert('Ingresa una contraseña.');history.back();</script>";
    elseif(empty($_POST["name"]))   echo "<script>alert('Ingresa tu nombre.');history.back();</script>";
    elseif(empty($_POST["last-name"])) echo "<script>alert('Ingresa tu apellido.');history.back();</script>";
    elseif($_POST["password"] != $_POST["rpassword"]) echo "<script>alert('Las contraseñas no coinciden.');history.back();</script>";
    elseif(!validate_mail($_POST["mail"])) echo "<script>alert('El e-mail es incorrecto.');history.back();</script>";
    else
    {
        $con = new mysqli("localhost", "universalistas", "u12345", "universalistas");
        $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["user"]);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password"]);
        $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["mail"]);
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $lastname = $_POST["last-name"];
        $origin = $_POST["origin"];
        $area = $_POST["area"];
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name='".$user."'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) echo "<script>alert('El usuario ya existe.');history.back();</script>";
        else
        {
            $password = md5($password); //Encriptacion md5
            $reg = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user (user_name, user_password, user_mail, name, last_name, origin, area) 
                VALUES ('".$user."', '".$password."', '".$mail."', '".$name."', '".$lastname."', '".$origin."', '".$area."')");
            if($reg)
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Usuario registrado correctamente.'); 
                window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo"<script>alert('¡Ha ocurrido un error y no se registraron los datos!'); 
                window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}

else {}

ob_end_flush() ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Lo probé antes en servidor local con xampp y ahora trato de pasarlo a un servicio de hosting (godaddy) y me lleva a la condición else '¡Ha ocurrido un error y no se registraron los datos!' (soy principiante)

Comment: Cambiaste la configuración de la conexión según tu acceso a tu espacio en godaddy?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que tu base de datos está en localhost? Es posible que Godaddy tenga la base de datos en otro servidor distinto al del php y por eso no te está funcionando. Pon en tu pregunta el error que te manda, si te manda algo, o metelo en un try catch.

Answer (score 0):

El código que estas mostrando esta conectando directamente al localhost, cambia esa configuración con la información que te brinda Godaddy.

```html
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "universalistas", "u12345", "universalistas");
```

seria algo como :

```html
$con = new mysqli("ip_publica_que_da_godaddy", "user_creado_bd_godaddy", "contraseña_que_configuraste", "bd_creada(la puedes exportar a GD)");
```

Saludos

Comment: especifica y añade la linea:         $con = new mysqli("localhost", "universalistas", "u12345", "universalistas");

Answer (score -1):

Es muy importante entender que la estructura de las condicionales es la siguiente:

```
If ( condición )
{ 
//código a ejecutar
}
 else
{
 //código a ejecutar 
 }
```

Debes de abrir llaves y cerrarlas, dentro de estas llaves escribes el código que deseas ejecutar. Este es el error, agrega las llaves en todas las condicionales, porque no las tienes.

Recuerda que trabajando en el entorno local xampp que está hecho para desarrollo más no para producción, esto significa que errores comunes los ignora, mientras que ya un servidor tiene  configuraciones muy específicas y toca tener el código correctamente.

Comment: Cuando el codigo compila, no importa el entorno, va a compilar igual en cualquier lado, ya que el compilador asi sea en produccion o en desarrollo es el mismo. Ademas, xampp es un paquete de programas, que son exactamente los mismos que vas a poner en un servidor. No hay diferencias...